# Templating library in node.js similar to Jinja2 in Python?

Tags: python, node.js, jinja2, language-comparisons

What would be a node.js templating library that is similar to Jinja2 in Python?

Comment: I would prefer [nunjucks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nunjucks), as it was even *referred* by jinja2

Answer (score 33):

https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks

Nunjucks is basically a JS port of Jinja2

Comment: https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks - they moved webpage here

Answer (score 6):

Maybe a list of template engines for node.js can help here too.

## List of template engines

- **[Pug](https://github.com/pugjs/pug)**: Haml-inspired template engine (formerly Jade).
- **[Haml.js](https://github.com/tj/haml.js)**: Haml implementation.
- **[EJS](https://github.com/mde/ejs)**: Embedded JavaScript template engine.
- **[hbs](https://github.com/pillarjs/hbs)**: Adapter for Handlebars.js, an extension of Mustache.js template engine.
- **[Squirrelly](https://github.com/squirrellyjs/squirrelly)**: Blazing-fast template engine that supports partials, helpers, custom tags, filters, and caching. Not white-space sensitive, works with any language.
- **[Eta](https://github.com/eta-dev/eta)**: Super-fast lightweight embedded JS template engine. Supports custom delimiters, async, whitespace control, partials, caching, plugins.
- **[React](https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views)**: Renders React components on the server. It renders static markup and does not support mounting those views on the client.
- **[combyne.js](https://github.com/tbranyen/combyne)**: A template engine that hopefully works the way you'd expect.
- **[Nunjucks](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks)**: Inspired by jinja/twig.
- **[marko](https://github.com/marko-js/marko)**: A fast and lightweight HTML-based templating engine that compiles templates to CommonJS modules and supports streaming, async rendering and custom tags. (Renders directly to the HTTP response stream).
- **[whiskers](https://github.com/gsf/whiskers.js)**: Small, fast, mustachioed.
- **[Blade](https://github.com/bminer/node-blade)**: HTML Template Compiler, inspired by Jade & Haml.
- **[Haml-Coffee](https://github.com/netzpirat/haml-coffee)**: Haml templates where you can write inline CoffeeScript.
- **[express-hbs](https://github.com/barc/express-hbs)**: Handlebars with layouts, partials and blocks for express 3 from Barc.
- **[express-handlebars](https://github.com/express-handlebars/express-handlebars)**: A Handlebars view engine for Express which doesn't suck.
- **[express-views-dom](https://github.com/AndersDJohnson/express-views-dom)**: A DOM view engine for Express.
- **[rivets-server](https://github.com/AndersDJohnson/rivets-server)**: Render Rivets.js templates on the server.
- **[LiquidJS](https://github.com/harttle/liquidjs)**: A simple, expressive and safe template engine.
- **[express-tl](https://github.com/Drulac/express-tl)**: A template-literal engine implementation for Express.
- **[Twing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twing)**: First-class Twig engine for Node.js.
- **[Sprightly](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sprightly)**: A very light-weight JS template engine (45 lines of code), that consists of all the bare-bones features that you want to see in a template engine.

(Some of these libs may be outdated or unmaintained.)

[Source expressjs](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html)

Answer (score 4):

[jinja-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jinja-js) aims to fe a feature complete reimplementation of the jinja2 template engine in Javascript. To my understanding the other options mentioned here some of the many, many templating engine options available for Javascript.

Comment: Recommendation requests for off-site resources or tools are off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you answer them, you specifically reinforce the belief that Stack Overflow is a good place to answer those questions. It is not. Please don't answer these questions even if you know a good answer as most answers will be highly opinionated ("I personally like..."). You can open the flag dialogue on the question and see the close reason in full under the **off-topic** category, or in the [help/on-topic]. You should also not even answer in a comment, as the effect is similar to an actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Nunjucks](http://jlongster.github.io/nunjucks/) & [Swig](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig)

This 2 are similar Django, Jinja2, and Twig template engines.

Comment: Swig is no longer maintained according to its github page https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig

Answer (score 1):

The ejs is the npm module which you are looking for.

- This is the name written in my package.json file --> "ejs": "^3.1.3"
- EJS is a simple templating language that lets you generate HTML markup with plain JavaScript.(Credits: Ejs website)